# Reading Samsung TecTile through mobile web

Tags: android, jquery, html, nfc

I can see there is way to access NFC reader to read Samsung TechTile, on mobile using android native App. But is there any way to access NFC reader to read Samsung TecTiles using mobile web which is developed in any technology like JQuery mobile, HTML5 etc..? or is there any library or solution which can help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Web NFC API under development (see http://www.w3.org/2012/nfc/web-api/ and https://github.com/w3c/nfc). However, that API is still in draft status and hardly any browsers support it.

- See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NFC_API/Using_the_NFC_API for Firefox support.
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/WebNFC for Mozilla's development status.
- See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-nfc for Chrome support.
- Slides from NFC Forum developer spotlight: http://nfc-forum.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Stickman-NFC-Forum-Developer-Spotlight-2014.pdf

Unfortunately, none of this brings Web NFC API support to Android so far.